# How to draw a contour map of $ f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have used a program to see that it is an ellipse but I want to know the process of thinking to actually draw the contour map myself.

$x^2+y^2+xy=C$ for $C=0,1,2,3,...$

I can't seem to get it into an ellipse form. What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: this is quadratic either in $x$ or $y$. you ought to be able to put in a box $a \le x \le b$ and $c \le y \le d$ for a fixed $C$ just by looking at the discriminant.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you have some knowledge of linear algebra.

The quadratic form $x^2 + 2 \frac{1}{2} xy + y^2$ can also be written as a dot product between two vectors

$$x^2 + 2 \frac{1}{2} xy + y^2 = \langle \left (\begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1 \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left (\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right ) , \left (\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right ) \rangle= \langle M v, v \rangle$$

Let's look a bit at the matrix of this quadratic form

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1 \end{array} \right )$$

It is a real symmetric matrix so it has real eigenvalues and it has a orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. The eigenvalues are $3/2$ and $1/2$ and we also obtain unit eigenvectors:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & 1 \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left (\begin{array}{c} 1/\sqrt{2}\\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{array} \right ) = 3/2 \cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} 1/\sqrt{2}\\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{array} \right )\\
\left(\begin{array}{cc}  1 &1/2\\1/2 & 1 \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left (\begin{array}{c} -1/\sqrt{2}\\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{array} \right ) = 1/2 \cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{array} \right )
$$

Therefore we have the equality:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & 1 \end{array} \right )  \cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}  1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{array} \right) =\left(\begin{array}{cc}  1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{array} \right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}  3/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 \end{array} \right )  $$
or 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & 1 \end{array} \right )  =  \left(\begin{array}{cc}  1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{array} \right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}  3/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}  1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{array} \right)^{-1} $$
we wrote the matrix of the quadratic form $M$ as 
$$M = R\cdot D \cdot R^{-1}$$

where $D$ is the diagonal matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}  3/2 & 0\\ 0 & 1/2 \end{array} \right )$ formed with the eigenvalues and $R$ is the rotation matrix formed with the corresponding unit eigenvectors $R = \left(\begin{array}{cc}  1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}  \cos\frac{\pi}{4} & -\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \\ \sin \frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4} \end{array} \right) $

The equation in the vector $v$ giving the curve is 
$$\langle Mv, v \rangle = C$$

or 
$$\langle R D R^{-1} v, v \rangle = C$$

The rotation matrix $R$ preserves the dot product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ so we have $ \langle R D R^{-1} v, v \rangle = \langle  D R^{-1} v, R^{-1} v \rangle $

Therefore the equation of the curve is 
$$\langle  D R^{-1} v, R^{-1} v \rangle  = C$$

Denote by $w = R^{-1} v$. We have $\langle  D w, w \rangle  = C$ and this equation in $w$ give an ellipse in standard form $E_0$. Our curve consists of all $v$ so that $w = R^{-1} v \in E_0$, that is $v \in R E_0$. Therefore, our curve is the rotation of the ellipse $E_0$ by the matrix $R$. Note that $R$ is a rotation of angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ counterclockwise.

$E_0$ is the ellipse $3/2\cdot  x^2 + 1/2\cdot y^2 = C$. Our curve $E$ is the rotation counterclockwise of $E_0$ by angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$

In general, if the matrix of the quadratic form is $M = R_{\alpha} D R_{\alpha}^{-1}$, then the curve 
$$\langle Mv, v\rangle = C$$ 
is the rotation by angle $\alpha$ of the conic
$$\langle D w, w \rangle = C$$
[image]

Obs: It's customary that for ellipses in standard form the longer axis is along the $x$-axis. Therefore, it seems preferable to use the decomposition $M = R D R^{-1}$ where the diagonal of  $D$ has elements in increasing order.  We notice that our curves are also rotations with angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$  clockwise of ellipses $1/2\cdot x^2 + 3/2\cdot y^2 =C$.

Comment: i think this is way more than an over kill.

Comment: @abel:  I do not agree.  This is the most conceptual way to approach the problem IMHO.

Comment: @StevenGubkin, see claude's answer.

Comment: I did.  I still think treating this function like what it is (a quadratic form) is the way to go!  For me, this is much easier to think about, and would actually be faster than Claude's solution (even though it might not look that way from the amount of ink spilled over the solution).

Comment: Neat. But too much overcomplicated and detailed. +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use brute force, consider $$x^2+y^2+x*y=C$$ as a quadratic equation in $y$; there are two solutions given by $$y_{\pm}=-\frac{1}{2} \left(x \pm \sqrt{4 C-3 x^2}\right)$$ To have the contour plot, both curves must be plotted and, because of the radical, choose the $x$ values in the range $$-\frac{2 \sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{3}} \leq x \leq \frac{2 \sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is a rotated ellipse.

You can get rid of the $xy$ term to obtain the usual ellipse equation in rotated axes.

Read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Say if you need exact derivation.